# How to force break a th tag as a line in table css

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-5

i'm trying to create a jquery datatable style responsiveness in an angular table child component. i was able to separate the td and th separately using absolute and relative positions. but the problem now i face is like this the th tag is not breaking at the end od the line and is clogged up as a single line need help to overcome this problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2u5b.png)

my code is as follows:

css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px){
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    table th {
        word-wrap: break-word;         /* All browsers since IE 5.5+ */
        overflow-wrap: break-word;     /* Renamed property in CSS3 draft spec */
    }
    .no-more-tables tbody, 
    .no-more-tables tr,
    .no-more-tables td{
        display: block;
        // position:absolute;
        // padding: 15px !important;
    }
    .no-more-tables thead th{
        position: absolute;
        // top: 67px;
        left: 204px;
    }
    .no-more-tables tr{
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50% !important;

    }
    .no-more-tables td:before{
        content: attr(data-title);
        position: relative;
        left: 16px;
    }
    th{
        .aligninline{
            display: block;
            align-items:center;
            // min-width:60px;
            background-color: transparent !important;
        }
    
      
    
    }
    
}


.hide{
display: none;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:15px;
   
    font-size: 10px;
}
.fon-wgt-50{
    font-weight: 50;
}
.cdk-overlay-contaniner,.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper{
    top: 30px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}

.bluetext{
    color:#0052cc;
}
.font-wgt{
font-weight: bolder !important;
}

.center-aligned{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
margin-left: 10px !important;
}
.darktext{
    color: #77b900;
}

.darktext:hover{
    color:#0052cc;
}


.bluetext:hover{
    color:#012840;
}

.cw{
    width:90px !important;
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

@media (max-width: 589px){
    .cw{
     
        justify-content: flex-start !important;
    }
}

.tablecomponent{
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
   
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:white;
}

.mainsection{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.block-show{
    display:block;
}

.headerleftsection1{
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: flex-end !important;
  
    min-height: 30px;
    margin-left:auto !important;
    
}
@media only screen and  (max-width:600px) {
    .headerleftsection1{
margin-left:0px !important;

}
}

thead{
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.headerleftsection{
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    min-height: 30px;

}

.headerleftsectionSearch{
    width: auto;
}

.pagecontroller{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:1024px)
{
    .pagecontroller{
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
}
.paginatorsection{
    padding:13px 32px 23px 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.paginator{
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 60px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.dflex{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tableheadersection{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    // align-items: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background-color:white;
    padding:23px 12px 23px 12px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.custommargin{
    margin : 0em 1em 1em 1em;
}

.paginatorbutton{
    min-width: 30px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #D9D9D9;
    border-radius:5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

select{
    padding:5px;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid#D9D9D9;
    border-radius:5px;
    align-self: center;
    font-size:1em;
    // min-height:43px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    color:#465E73;
}

option{
    // padding:20px;
    background-color:white;
    margin: 10px;
}

.actionIcon::ng-deep svg path {
    fill: white !important;
  }
.actionIcon{
    circle{
    fill:white !important;
  }
}

.isDisabled{
    background-color:lightgray;
}

select {
    box-sizing: content-box;
 padding: 5px 0;
  }

.paginatorsection label{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.gotoinput{
    min-width: 80px;
        margin: 2px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
        border-radius: 5px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 589px){
    p{
        color:#465E73;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    .paginatorbutton{
        min-width: 20px;
        margin: 2px;
        padding:5px;
        border:1px solid #D9D9D9;
        border-radius:5px;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    
}

thead th{
    padding:12px;
    color:#465E73;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    p{
        color:#465E73;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 1em !important;
    }


    th{
        .aligninline{
            display: flex;
            align-items:center;
            text-align: center;
            // min-width:60px;
            background-color: transparent !important;
        }
        font-weight: 250;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-right: 13px;
    
    }
    
}

th{
    .aligninline{
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        // min-width:60px;
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    font-size: 16px;
    margin-right: 13px;
    font-weight: 250;
    // min-width: 120px !important;
    // max-width: 400px !important;

}

tr{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #97919129;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    th{
        .aligninline{
            display: flex;
            align-items:center;
            // min-width:60px;
            background-color: transparent !important;
        }
    
        font-size: 16px !important;
        margin-right: 13px;
        font-weight: 250;
    }

    tbody tr td{
        padding:12px;
        color: #465E73;
        font-size: 1em !important;
        
    }    
}

tbody tr td{
    padding:14px;
    color: #6f6e6e !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    
}

.tablefootersection{
    background-color:white;
    padding:23px 32px 23px 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    font-weight: 50;
    font-size: 10px;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #465E73;
}

.filtersection{
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.alignContentCenter{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}

.dot{
    min-width: 10px;
    min-height: 10px;
    max-width: 10px;
    max-height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #BF2A37;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.margin1{
    margin: .25rem .25rem 0px!important;
}

.gotoinput{
    // border:0px;
    // border-bottom: 1px solid #00000029;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 5px;
}

.inline{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
 
}


.leftarrow{
    width: 50%;
}

.rightarrow{
    transform: rotate(180deg);   
    width:50%;
}

@media(max-width:877px){
    .headerleftsection{
        display: flex;
        // flex:1;
        align-items: baseline;
        justify-content:space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
        // margin-top: 15px;
        min-height: 30px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:1024px){
th{
    font-size:1em;
}
td{
    font-size:1em !important;
}
}
@media(max-width:769px){
    th{
        font-size:0.9em;
    }
    td{
        font-size:0.8em !important;
    }
    select{
        font-size:1em;
      
    }
    }


@media(max-width:375px){
    .tableheadersection{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        // align-items: center;
        align-items: flex-end;
        background-color:white;
        padding:23px 12px 23px 12px;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}

@media(max-width:490px){
    .mt10{
        margin-top:10px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1030px){
    .filtersection app-drop-down{
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
    .green-button-sm{
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
}


.multiActions{
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

here is the html part:

```
<p class="heading" >{{tableTitle}} <app-icon *ngIf="tableTitle != ''" [matTooltip]="toolTip" ></app-icon> </p>

<!-- <div class="row">

    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Add Vacancy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <select class="form-select form-select mb-3"  >
            <option>123</option>
            <option>123</option>
            <option>123</option>
            <option>123</option>
        </select>
    </div>


</div> -->
<div class="tablec" >
    <!-- <table width="100%" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"  class="table row-border hover"></table> -->
    <div [style.boxShadow]="!dropShadow?'none':''" class="tablecomponent" >
    <div class="tableheadersection"
    [style.padding]="tableHeaderFooterPadding"
    [style.padding]="tableHeaderPadding"
    *ngIf="(showTopPaginator || showColorIndicators || showTopDropdown)"
    >
       
        <div *ngIf="showTopPaginator" class="headerleftsection" >
            <div *ngIf="TopDropdown" class="pagecontroller select" >
                <p>Show</p>
                <select class="select" (change)="changePageSize($event)" [value]="selectedPageSize"  >
                    <option value="5" [selected]="DefPageSizeselect===5">5</option>
                    <option value="10" [selected]="DefPageSizeselect===10">10</option>
                    <option value="25" [selected]="DefPageSizeselect===25">25</option>
                    <option value="50" [selected]="DefPageSizeselect===50">50</option>
                    <option value="100" [selected]="DefPageSizeselect===100">100</option>
                </select>
               
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="showColorIndicators" class="custommargin" >
                <app-color-indicators
                  [indicators1]="colorIndicators1"
                ></app-color-indicators>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="showTopDropdown" class="headerleftsection" >
            <app-drop-down class="margin1" 
            [labelName]="firstDropdownLabelName"
            [dropdownValues$]="topFirstDropdowns$"
            (onChangeValue)="onFirstDropDownChange($event)"
            [autoSelect]="false"
            ></app-drop-down>

            <app-drop-down 
            class="margin1"
            [labelName]="secondDropdownLabelName"
            [dropdownValues$]="topSecondDropdowns$"
            (onChangeValue)="onSecondDropDownChange($event)"
            (entireRowValuesOutput)="EmissionFromSecondDropdown($event)"
            [autoSelect]="false"
            ></app-drop-down>
        </div>
        <div class="dflex pl4 dflex--mod" *ngIf="!hideTopActionDropdown" >
         <div class="filtersection" >
            <ng-container *ngFor="let tablefilter of (topdropdownFilters$ | async)" >

                <app-drop-down
                *ngIf="!tablefilter.multiselect"
                class="mx-1"
                [dropdownValues$]="tablefilter.options"
                (onChangeValue)="dropdownFilterChanged($event)"
                [inputName]="tablefilter.name"
                [labelName]="tablefilter.label"
                [autoSelect]="false"
                ></app-drop-down>
<!-- 
                <app-multiple-select-dropdown
                [label]="tablefilter.label"
                [labelName]="tablefilter.labelName"
                *ngIf="tablefilter.multiselect"
                [dropdownValues$] = "tablefilter.options"
                (checkBoxSelected)="multipleDropdownSelectedValues($event)"
               
                ></app-multiple-select-dropdown> -->
               
            </ng-container>
          
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dflex pl4 dflex--mod" *ngIf="hideTopActionDropdown1" >
            <app-drop-down 
           
            [dropdownValues$]="topActionDropdowns$" class="mr1" inputName="client_actions" [autoSelect]="true" [labelName]="selected" (onChangeValue)="onTopActionDropdownChange($event)" ></app-drop-down>
            <button class="red-btn addbutton" *ngIf="dropDownButtonShow" (click)="TopActionButton($event)" >{{TopdropDownButtonName}}</button>
  
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="showSearchbar"  class="headerleftsection1 headerleftsectionSearch mt10 mr-1 " >
            <app-text-input class="searchinput" 
            [showTextError]="false" 
            (keydown.enter)="search($event)" 
            (input)="reload($event)"
            [placeholder]="placeholder" 
            (onReset)="reset($event)"
            ></app-text-input>
        </div>

    </div>
    <section class="p-5">
    <div class="mainsection table-responsive" >
     
        <table
       class="table no-more-tables"
       id="no-more-tables"
        >
     
                <tr>
                    <th class="" *ngFor="let heading of columndata$ | async; let i=index" >
                    <div *ngIf="heading.columnDef != 'checkbox'" >
                       <div class="aligninline font-wgt"  [style.justifyContent]="heading.align ? heading.align : '' " >
                        <span (click)="headingClicked($event)" >
                            {{heading.columnDef}}
                            <!-- | flatCaseForTow  -->
                        </span> 
                        <app-sort-icon
                        *ngIf="heading.sorting"
                        [sortName] = "heading.header"
                        (onSort) = "onChangeSort($event)"
                        ></app-sort-icon>
                       </div>
                      
                    </div>    
                    <div class="aligninline" *ngIf="heading.columnDef === 'checkbox'">
                        <mat-checkbox
                        (change)="selectAllRows()"
                        [(ngModel)]="checkedAll"
                        >
                        </mat-checkbox>
                    </div>    
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let data of tabaledata$ | async;let j=index"  (click)="rowSelect(data)"  (mouseenter)="eventEnter(data)" >
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let heading of (columndata$ | async);let i = index" >
                        <td data-title="{{heading.columnDef}}" *ngIf="heading.columnDef == 'checkbox'" >
                            <mat-checkbox
                            [checked] = "data.checkbox"
                            (click)="rowChecked(data)"
                            >
                            </mat-checkbox>
                        </td>
                        <td data-title="{{heading.columnDef}}"  class="fon-wgt-50" *ngIf="heading.columnDef !== 'checkbox'" >
                            <!-- [style.backgroundColor]="heading?.changeColor?heading?.backgroundColor(data):''"  -->

                                <container-element [ngSwitch]="heading.type" [ngClass]="{'inline': heading.type === 'link'}" >
                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'link'"  >
                                        <ng-container *ngIf="heading.dot"  >
                                            <div class="dot" [style.background-color]="clientColorStatus(heading.dotClass(data))" *ngIf="clientColorStatus(heading.dotClass(data)) != 'white'" ></div>
                                        </ng-container>
                                        
                                       <a [routerLink]="heading.link(data)" class="bluetext" >{{heading.cell(data)}}</a> 
                                       <ng-template *ngIf="heading.postFixIcon">
                                       <img *ngIf="heading.postFixIcon(data) == 0" src="./../../../assets/comman/eligo.png" />
                                       <img *ngIf="heading.postFixIcon(data) == 1" src="./../../../assets/comman/icon.png" />
                                    </ng-template>
                                    </ng-container>

                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'action'" >
                                        <div class="multiActions"  [style.justifyContent]="heading.align ? heading.align : '' " >
                                       <ng-container *ngFor="let link of heading.links"  >
                                       
                                            <a style="cursor: pointer;" [routerLink]="link.action(data)" [class]="link.image(data) == '' ? 'bluetext' : 'darktext'" class="aligncenter" >
                                             
                                                <i [class]="link.image(data)" ></i>
                                                <span (click)="link?.onClick(data)" [class]="link?.class && link.text(data) != '' ? link.class(data) : ''"  class="m-1" >{{link.text(data)}}</span> 
                                            </a>
                                           
                                       </ng-container>
                                       </div>
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'button'" >
                                        <div class="multiActions"  [style.justifyContent]="heading.align ? heading.align : '' " >
                                       <ng-container *ngFor="let link of heading.links"  >
                                            <button class="m-1"  [routerLink]="link.action(data)" (click)="link?.onClick(data)" [class]="link.color(data)" class="aligncenter" >
                                             
                                                <i [class]="link.image(data)" ></i>
                                                <span  class="m-1" >{{link.text(data)}}</span> 
                                            </button>
                                       </ng-container>
                                       </div>
                                    </ng-container>
                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"  >
                                            <ng-container *ngFor="let link of heading.links" >
                                                <select (change)="link?.onClick($event,data)" [disabled]="link.isDisabled(data)" [ngClass]="{'isDisabled':link.isDisabled(data)}" >
                                                    <option value="" ></option>
                                                    <ng-container *ngFor="let value of link.text(data)|async" >
                                                        <option  value="{{link.valueKey(value)}}" [selected]="link.valueKey(value) == heading.cell(data)" class="optionsFont" >{{value.name}}</option>
                                                    </ng-container>
                                                </select>
                                                </ng-container>
                                    </ng-container>


                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault >
                                       {{heading.cell(data) == 'null' ? '' : heading.cell(data)}}
                                    </ng-container>
                                  </container-element>
                          
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                </tr>
                <tr *ngIf="(!(tabaledata$ | async) || ((tabaledata$ | async)?.length == 0) )" >
                    <td [attr.colspan]="(columndata$ | async)?.length" style="text-align:center" ><img src="./assets/images/nodata-image.png"><br>There is no data to display</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
    <div 
    [style.padding]="tableHeaderFooterPadding"
    *ngIf="showFooterDropdown" class="tablefootersection" >
        <div class="dflex pl4 dflex--mod" *ngIf="!hideActionDropdown" >
            <app-drop-down 
           
            [dropdownValues$]="actionDropdowns$" class="mr1" inputName="client_actions" [autoSelect]="true" [labelName]="selected" (onChangeValue)="onActionDropdownChange($event)" ></app-drop-down>
            <button class="btn btn-sm green-button-sm btn-outline-primary applytobeselectedbutton" (click)="ActionButton($event)" >{{dropDownButtonName}}</button>
  
        </div>
        <div class="filtersection" >
            <ng-container *ngFor="let tablefilter of (dropdownFilters$ | async)" >

                <app-drop-down
                *ngIf="!tablefilter.multiselect"
                class="mx-1"
                [dropdownValues$]="tablefilter.options"
                (onChangeValue)="dropdownFilterChanged($event)"
                [inputName]="tablefilter.name"
                [labelName]="tablefilter.label"
                [autoSelect]="false"
                ></app-drop-down>

                <app-multiple-select-dropdown
                [label]="tablefilter.label"
                [labelName]="tablefilter.labelName"
                *ngIf="tablefilter.multiselect"
                [dropdownValues$] = "tablefilter.options"
                (checkBoxSelected)="multipleDropdownSelectedValues($event)"
               
                ></app-multiple-select-dropdown>
               
            </ng-container>
          
        </div>
    
    </div>
    <div 
    [style.padding]="tableHeaderFooterPadding"
    class="paginatorsection" >

        <div>
            <button *ngIf="showFooterLeftButton" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="leftbuttonAction($event)" >{{FooterLeftButtonText}}</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-end flex-wrap" *ngIf="Paginator1" >
          
            <div class="paginator" *ngIf="showBottomPaginator" >
                <div class="d-inline-flex align-self-center cw" >
                    <label>Page</label>
                    <input class="gotoinput" type="number" min="0" (keydown.enter)="gotoPageAction($event)" placeholder="No"  />
                </div>
                <div class="alignContentCenter paginatordiv" >
                    <p>{{(tabaledetails$ | async)?.start}} - {{ (((tabaledetails$ | async)?.total) < ((tabaledetails$ | async)?.end)+((tabaledetails$ | async)?.start)) ? (tabaledetails$ | async)?.total : ((tabaledetails$ | async)?.end)+((tabaledetails$ | async)?.start) -1 }} of {{(tabaledetails$ | async)?.total}} </p>
                  </div>
                
                <div class="paginatorbutton" *ngIf="!(((tabaledetails$ | async)?.page_num)<= 1)" (click)="paginatorEventEmitter('previouspage')" >
                    <img src="./assets/comman/arrow.svg" class="leftarrow" />
                </div>

                <div class="paginatorbutton" >
                    {{(tabaledetails$ | async)?.page_num}}
                </div>
               

                <div class="paginatorbutton"
                *ngIf="(((tabaledata$ | async)?.length >= selectedPageSize) && readAsNumber((((tabaledetails$ | async)?.total) < ((tabaledetails$ | async)?.end)+((tabaledetails$ | async)?.start)) ? (tabaledetails$ | async)?.total : ((tabaledetails$ | async)?.end)+((tabaledetails$ | async)?.start) -1) < readAsNumber((tabaledetails$ | async)?.total)  )"
                (click)="paginatorEventEmitter('nexpage')">
                <img src="./assets/comman/arrow.svg" class="rightarrow" />
            </div>


               

            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-end flex-wrap" *ngIf="Paginator2" >
            
            <div class="paginator" *ngIf="showBottomPaginator" >
             <div class="alignContentCenter" >
                    <p>{{(tabaledetails$ | async)?.total}}</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="paginatorbutton" *ngIf="(((tabaledetails$ | async)?.previous)!= null)" (click)="paginator2EventEmitter('previouspage')" >
                    <img src="./assets/comman/arrow.svg" class="leftarrow" />
                </div>

                <div class="paginatorbutton" >
                    {{(tabaledetails$ | async)?.page_num}}
                </div>
                <div class="paginatorbutton"  (click)="paginator2EventEmitter('nexpage')" >
                    <img src="./assets/comman/arrow.svg" class="rightarrow"  />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

i can't recreate a min sample example as it is a project. Since it is just css i think experts like you will be able to crack it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: If the problem is just a CSS problem then you should be able to create a minimal reproducible example using just CSS.

Comment: Did you know that Stack snippets allow you to include Angular and Bootstrap as part of your minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the **generated** code (view source in your browser), that will be more useful as a starting point than your angular source code. Once we figure out what's wrong the in the generated code, then if necessary we backtrack from there to determine what's wrong in the source.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get sample.
that picture can't explain your problem.
but try that

```
table th {
    word-break: break-word;
}
```